# Does .editorconfig have a setting for spacing around logical operators in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, editorconfig

I've found a list of Visual Studio .editorconfig settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference#formatting-conventions). But I'm not sure if it is complete or not. It contains a list of five spacing settings, none of which seem to be relevant for the setting I want.

In particular, I want to control spacing around logical operators, such as:

```
if (x!=0)
if (x != 0)
```

EDIT: I am specifically asking about .editorconfig. The key is that it is a setting inside the solution, not in Visual Studio settings.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get Visual Studio 2017 to do this automatically. But do note that if you focus the code file then press `CTRL+A`, `CTRL+X`, `CTRL+V` in order, all of your code in the file will be reformatted according to the settings, including spacing between operators and variables/literals.

Comment: There is a way, in code formatting settings for vs. But I can't find one in editorconfig.

Comment: You can format code in VS with [CTRL]+[ K ], [CTRL] + [ D ].

Comment: Does `spaces_around_operators = true` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [.editorconfig reference](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/editorconfig-reference-for-c-developers#csharp_space_around_binary_operators) it looks like what you need would be the line below:

```
csharp_space_around_binary_operators  = before_and_after
```

It mentions there that this flag is "currently thwarted by [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20355)".